# Saving the value of html select option in database using Laravel controller

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I am currently working on a Laravel project and I need to save the content of the data received during user registration in a table called users.i was able to save other values correctly in the table except the value of the  html select options.

Below is my html form:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="User_type" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Select User type'
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-input" name="signup_type">
          <option value="single_user">single_user</option>
          <option value="multi_user">multi_user</option>    
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my laravel controller to add the needed values to database:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
   return Validator::make(
   $data, ['user_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:32', 'unique:users'],
   'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
   'mobile_phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:15',           'unique:users'],
   'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
   'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
   'signup_type' => ['required','string','max:30'],]
    );
   }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
protected function create(array $data)
  {
     if (substr($data['mobile_phone'], 0, 1) == 0) {
          $data['mobile_phone'] = substr(
          $data['mobile_phone'], 1, strlen($data['mobile_phone'])-1
          );
      }
      $data['mobile_phone'] = $data['dialingcode'].$data['mobile_phone'];
      return User::create(
        ['user_name' => $data['user_name'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'mobile_phone' => $data['mobile_phone'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'signup_type' => $data['signup_type'],
        'role_id' => 1,]
      );  
}
```

but each time I check the value of signup_type in database it is always null.

Comment: check in the User model the fillable/guarded array please, if there you can't find anything strange, please post the whole html form

Comment: @Berto99 thanks a lot,i forgot i did not add signup_type to the user model,i modified the registration page of recent to include signup_type and i forgot to add it to the signup_type...Problem solved!!!

Comment: oh grad to have helped, i'll add an answer in order to close the question

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer thanks...i will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check in the `User` model the `fillable` and the `guarded` arrays, in order to allow mass assignment also on that field.